# DJANGO : How to create admin view with a model containt order_by?

Tags: django, view, filter, admin

My model is

```
Class Document(models.Model):
    Contrat = Contrat.objects.order_by('Contrat_text').distinct('Contrat_text')
    isContrat = models.BooleanField(('Contrat'), default=True)
    isCdC = models.BooleanField(('Cahier des Charges'), default=False)
    isCR = models.BooleanField(('Cahier de Recette'), default=False)
    isPG = models.BooleanField(('PG'), default=False)
    isCI = models.BooleanField(('CI'), default=False)
    isDico = models.BooleanField(('Dictionnaire'), default=False)
    isSFG = models.BooleanField(('SFG'), default=False)
    isGuide = models.BooleanField(('Guide'), default=False)
    isWSDL = models.BooleanField(('WSDL'), default=False)
    isDivers = models.BooleanField(('Divers'), default=False)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.Contrat
```

How to create Admin view with the same filter ?

```
class DocumentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
fields = ('Contrat', 'isContrat', 'isCdC', 'isCR', 'isPG', 'isCI', 'isDico', 'isSFG', 'isGuide', 'isWSDL', 'isDivers')
list_display = ('Contrat', 'isContrat', 'isCdC', 'isCR', 'isPG', 'isCI', 'isDico', 'isSFG', 'isGuide', 'isWSDL', 'isDivers')
ordering = ('id',)
```

admin.site.register(Document, DocumentAdmin)

Comment: What do you try to do at the second and last two lines of your model? Does this code run at all?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Models Meta ordering: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/#ordering

```
class Item(models.Model):
    field_x = SomeField()
    field_y = SomeOtherField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['field_x']
```

Don't specify ordering on your ModelAdmin or queries. The ordering field on the model will be the default.

### UPDATE

At least the following is wrong with your code:

1) `Class` is with a lower case C. So `class`.

2) Queries aren't made *in* the model. But in views and managers etc. Remove: `Contrat = Contrat.objects.order_by('Contrat_text').distinct('Contrat_text')`

3) De `__str__` is used to give a string representation of the object. In self.Contract you query some other object. It doesn't make sense. Remove: `def __str__(self): return self.Contrat`.

4) The field titles should be strings not tuples.
`('Contrat')` should be `'Contrat'`, remove all those parentheses... Maybe if you use gettext it should be `_('Contract')`. But I doubt you try to use internationalization and localization.

5) A BooleanField is default False, so remove all `default=False`.

6) The indenting in modelAdmin is wrong. The fields should jump in.

I hope that's all. But I could have missed a thing or two. If you get an error, supply the traceback in your question.

Comment: it is not working !

model have :

    **Contrat = Contrat.objects.order_by('Contrat_text').distinct('Contrat_text')**

order_by and distinct from another model

i have this error :

    DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend

Comment: I interpreted your question as 'How do I set ordering on a model?'. That is the question I wrote an answer for. Now a error pops up! Why didn't you mention that before? Ask better questions and receive better answers.